# Magento problem with manufacturers in products

Tags: magento

Anyone have an idea how can I set a manufacturer for a product?

ex: I'm selling iphones and want to set Apple as its manufacturer/brand

Please help me with this simple task! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Magento has default attribute named '**manufacturer**'
- Edit attribute from **Catalog -> Attributes** and see if **Apple** is present as your attribute option
- Drag '**manufacturer**' attribute to your attribute set (**Catalog -> Attribute Set**)
- Edit product (**Catalog -> Manage Products**)
- You should see **Manufacturer** as a dropdown
- Select **Apple** from the dropdown
- Save the prodouct

Comment: is there any way I can add logos for manufacturers before I start coding?

Answer (score 1):

Also, if the manufacturer attribute is defined as a dropdown (which seems to be the default), the manufacturer must be added to the attribute list before you try to import product with a manufacturer. And your manufacturers listed in the imports must be direct matches to those contained in the manufacturer attribute list.